# I want to cross join two table but shows one of the table NULL's values. Should i use right outer join?

Tags: sql-server, select, left-join, cross-join, right-join

I have a Table1:

> IdT1, IdT1Group
>
> 11,       30
>
> 12,       30
>
> 13,       30

Table2:

> IdT2 , IdT1,  Detail
>
> 2  ,  11 ,    A
>
> 3  ,  11 ,    B
>
> 4  ,  12 ,    A
>
> 5  ,  12 ,    B

I expect my query to be:

> IdT2, IdT1, Detail
>
> 2     ,   11 ,    A
>
> 3     ,   11 ,    B
>
> 2     ,   12 ,    A
>
> 3     ,   12 ,    B
>
> NULL , 13  ,  A
>
> NULL , 13  ,  B

So, I Use Cross Join:

```
SELECT  table2.IdT2, 
        table1.IdT1, table2.Detail
FROM    table2 CROSS JOIN table1
WHERE   table2.IdT1 = 11 AND table1.IdT1Group = 30
```

But after i tried my code, it was:

```
IdT2    IdT1    Detail

2   ,   11  ,   A

3   ,   11  ,   B

2   ,   12  ,   A

3   ,   12  ,   B

2   ,   13  ,   A

3   ,   13  ,   B
```

This is what should it be:

```
IdT2, IdT1, Detail

2   ,   11 ,    A

3   ,   11 ,    B

2   ,   12 ,    A

3   ,   12 ,    B

NULL , 13  ,    A

NULL , 13  ,    B
```

If I use this query:

```
SELECT  T2.IdT2, tblJoin.IdT1, tblJoin.Detail

FROM    Table2 AS T2 RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT Table2.IdT2, 
            Table1.IdT1, Table2.Detail 
     FROM   Table2 CROSS JOIN Table1 WHERE  Table2.IdT1 = 11 AND Table1.IdT1Group = 30
    )   AS tblJoin ON T2.IdT1 = tblJoin.IdT1 And T2.IdT2 = tblJoin.IdT2 ORDER BY IdT2
```

The result would be:

> IdT2  , IdT1 , Detail
>
> NULL ,    12 ,    A
>
> NULL ,    12 ,    B
>
> NULL ,    13 ,    A
>
> NULL ,    13 ,    B
>
> 2 ,   11 ,    A
>
> 3 ,   11 ,    B

if Data On Table 2 is:

> IdT2 , IdT1,  Detail
>
> 2  ,  11 ,    A
>
> 3  ,  11 ,    B
>
> 4  ,  11 ,    C
>
> 5  ,  12 ,    A
>
> 6  ,  12 ,    B

, Data of the select that I've expect would be:

> IdT2 ; IdT1 ; Detail
>
> 2 ,   11 ,    A
>
> 3 ,   11 ,    B
>
> 4 ,   11 ,    C
>
> 2 ,   12 ,    A
>
> 3 ,   12 ,    B
>
> NULL ,    12 ,    C
>
> NULL ,    13  ,   A
>
> NULL ,    13  ,   B
>
> NULL ,    13  ,   C

Comment: How do you know if idt1 = 13 has two details A and B?

Comment: actually I was Select rows Where IdT1 = 11 for the key of Cross Join, so if on IdT1 (11) have 3 details on Table 2,

Data of the select that I've expect would be:

IdT2 : 2,3,4, 2,3,4 Null,Null,Null ; 

IdT1 : 11,11,11,12,12,12,13,13,13

Detail : A,B,C, A,B,C, A,B,C

Comment: Please edit your post with more sample data instead of adding the information in the comment.

Comment: You can't possibly be getting the results you say you are getting.  Your WHERE clause of `WHERE table2.IdT2 = 2` would prevent the rows with `idT2`=3 in the results.

Comment: Oh, yeah, i got wrong, it was : WHERE   table2.IdT1 = 11 (i want cross join the detail that Table1.11 have to all of other 11's group(30))

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see here with your result set you probably want something close to this.  Although it's challenging without much context.  See if that gets you closer to what you want  :)

```
SELECT t2.IdT2, t1.IdT1, d.Detail 
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.IdT1 = t2.IdT1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Detail FROM Table2 WHERE idT1=11 ) d
WHERE t1.IdT1Group=30
```

Comment: 1, Alias name should be t1.   2, t1 does not have a column [detail].

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't have a compiler for this.

Comment: But your query will return the idt1 = 13 with null detail. You can see your query output here:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bfc659a1fc961767ac64b7d615a1ea99

Comment: Thanks Gen Wan.  The dbfiddle helps!  Haven't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
WITH Table1( IdT1, IdT1Group)
AS
(
    SELECT 11, 30 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 30 UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, 30
),
Table2(IdT2 , IdT1, Detail)
AS
(
    SELECT 2 , 11 , 'A' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 , 11 , 'B' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 , 12 , 'A' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 , 12 , 'B'
)

SELECT D.IdT2,C.IdT1,C.Detail FROM 
(
    SELECT IdT1, Detail FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 1 JK,Detail FROM Table2
        -- Return DISTINCT LIST of Details as I seen 
        -- You established relation between all Distinct Details
        -- With All Number. JK (Joined Key) = 1 Generated so that 
        -- I can join both table by that number to create all to 
        -- all combination
    )A
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 1 JK,* FROM Table1
        -- JK (Joined Key) = 1 Generated so that I can join 
        -- both table by that number to create all to all combination
    )B ON A.JK = B.JK
)C
LEFT JOIN Table2 D ON C.IdT1 = D.IdT1 AND C.Detail = D.Detail
ORDER BY 2
```

Output is-

```
IdT2    IdT1    Detail
2       11      A
3       11      B
5       12      B
4       12      A
NULL    13      A
NULL    13      B
```

Comment: Thank You for the suggesting, but there's small mistake, i would like to get the IdT2 for 12(IdT1) is same with 11(IdT1)

Comment: With your changed data in Table2, you are expecting a row with combination '2 , 12 , A'. Can you please explain the logic?